# How to detect predisposition for magic in dnd?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, magic

In my campaign we inherited 2 children.
My mage character would like to know if one or both of the kids could become magic users.

How to do that? Is there a spell, ability check, or other ability to detect a predisposition for magic in children?

Comment: Welcome. What edition are you playing? Also, are you looking for an answer which is "rules as written" from the edition only or other editions. Or, looking for non-RAW answeres from DMs with lived experience of managing campaigns where this has happened?

Comment: This has a pretty consistent answer across at least Wizards of the Coast’s editions of D&D. It might change in different settings, but we can always answer for the implied setting of generic D&D (read: everything in the last 20+ years). It might be possible to write a _better_ answer for a particular edition, and/or a particular setting, but _an_ answer is possible generically. Thus this question should be open.

Comment: While this may be answerable for all editions, OP is playing a specific edition in a specific setting and it would be more helpful to give them an answer that applies to them. I'd prefer to wait until setting/edition are answered before we try to guess at what's important and relevant to them.

Comment: Voted to reopen because of sorcerers, especially draconic.

Comment: @AmethystWizard The question was closed because it lacks details necessary to provide a focused answer applicable in the game OP is playing, so “because sorcerers” makes little sense as a reason to reopen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Magic almost never comes from "predisposition" in D&D.

Sorcerors get their magic from inherited power, and that's about it. Every other magic-casting class (that appears in more than one edition) gets their powers from either studying magic or in exchange for worship/service of some powerful creature. So while yes, there might be some signs that the child in question has inherited power from a bloodline and can become a sorceror, the absence of those signs absolutely does **not** mean that child will not be capable of spellcasting. Their bloodline might not reveal itself until they're older, or they could acquire spells from literally *any other class*.

**Clerics** get their magic from their deity (or even just their intense devotion to an ideal). Anyone can do so (assuming you can get a deity to like you enough), though there's an element of perceptiveness/awareness to it that makes some better at it than others.

- From the 5e PHB: "Divine magic, as the name suggests, is the power of the gods, flowing from them into the world. Clerics are conduits for that power, manifesting it as miraculous effects. The gods don't grant this power to everyone who seeks it, but only to those chosen to fulfill a high calling. Harnessing divine magic doesn't rely on study or training. A cleric might learn formulaic prayers and ancient rites, but the ability to cast cleric spells relies on devotion and an intuitive sense of a deity's wishes."
- From the 4e PHB: "Power Source: Divine. You have been invested with the authority to wield divine power on behalf of a deity, faith, or philosophy."
- From the 3.5 PHB: "A cleric uses the power of his god to make the god's will manifest. And if a cleric uses his god's power to improve his own lot, that's to be expected too."
- From the AD&D 2e PHB: "The cleric receives his spells as insight directly from his deity (the deity does not need to make a personal appearance to grant the spells the cleric prays for), as a sign of and reward for his faith, so he must take care not to abuse his power lest it be taken away as punishment."

**Druids** get their magic either from a nature-focused deity (like clerics) or by attuning themselves with nature itself. Anyone who makes the effort to do that can become a druid, but again, as with clerics, some people with better innate perceptiveness will be better at it.

- From the 5e PHB: "Druids revere nature above all, gaining their spells and other magical powers either from the force of nature itself or from a nature deity. Many druids pursue a mystic spirituality of transcendent union with nature rather than devotion to a divine entity, while others serve gods of wild nature, animals, or elemental forces. The ancient druidic traditions are sometimes called the Old Faith, in contrast to the worship of gods in temples and shrines."
- From the 4e PHB2: "Power Source: Primal. You have gained your powers through a careful study of and communion with the natural world."
- From the 3.5 PHB: "The fury of a storm, the gentle strength of the morning sun, the cunning of the fox, the power of the bear - all these and more are at the druid's command. The druid, however, claims no mastery over nature. That claim, she says, is the empty boast of a city dweller. The druid gains her power not by ruling nature but by being at one with it."
- From the AD&D 2e PHB (where druids were just a special type of cleric): "The druid is an example of a priest designed for a specific mythos. His powers and beliefs are different from those of the cleric. The druid is a priest of nature and guardian of the wilderness, be it forest, plains, or jungle."

**Warlocks** get their magic from whatever powerful entity they bargained with. Anyone willing to contact such an entity can that, though people who are more persuasive & better at bargaining will obviously get a better deal.

- From the 5e PHB: "A warlock is defined by a pact with an otherworldly being. Sometimes the relationship between warlock and patron is like that of a cleric and a deity, though the beings that serve as patrons for warlocks are not gods. A warlock might lead a cult dedicated to a demon prince, an archdevil, or an utterly alien entity-beings not typically served by clerics. More often, though, the arrangement is similar to that between a master and an apprentice. The warlock learns and grows in power, at the cost of occasional services performed on the patron's behalf."
- From the 4e PHB: "Power Source: Arcane. You gain your magical power from a pact you forge with a powerful, supernatural force or an unnamed entity."
- In 3.5 (where warlocks were introduced), they were more like sorcerors. From the 3.5 Complete Mage: "Born of a supernatural bloodline, the warlock seeks to master the perilous magic that suffuses his soul." Presumably this was changed in later editions to better differentiate them from sorcerors as their mechanics became closer to the spellcasting of sorcerors.

**Wizards** get their magic from intense study & practice. Becoming a wizard is kind of like getting a masters degree in astrophysics or neuroscience. It's hard work and you have to be fairly intelligent, but anyone who meets those 2 requirements can accomplish it.

- From the 5e PHB: "Wild and enigmatic, varied in form and function, the power of magic draws students who seek to master its mysteries. Some aspire to become like the gods, shaping reality itself. Though the casting of a   typical spell requires merely the utterance of a   few strange words, fleeting gestures, and sometimes a pinch or clump of exotic materials, these surface components barely hint at the expertise attained after years of apprenticeship and countless hours of study. Wizards live and die by their spells. Everything else is secondary. They learn new spells as they experiment and grow in experience. They can also learn them from other wizards, from ancient tomes or inscriptions, and from ancient creatures (such as the fey) that are steeped in magic."
- From the 4e PHB: "Power Source: Arcane. You channel arcane forces through extensive study, hidden knowledge, and intricate preparation. To you, magic is an art form, an expressive and powerful method by which you seek to control the world around you."
- From the 3.5 PHB: "Wizards depend on intensive study to create their magic. They examine musty old tomes, debate magical theory with their peers, and practice minor magics whenever they can. For a wizard, magic is not a talent but a difficult, rewarding art."
- From the AD&D 2e PHB: "The wizard strives to be a master of magical energies, shaping them and casting them as spells. To do so, he studies strange tongues and obscure facts and devotes much of his time to magical research. A wizard must rely on knowledge and wit to survive."

Most other magic-using classes in D&D are just slightly different flavors of the classes above, or a blend of one of those classes plus fighter.

Note that while there is no inborn "spark" of magic that is needed to cast spells, almost all spellcasting classes require one of the mental ability scores to be above average (that is, greater than 10), either to take the class at all or to actually cast the spells acquired from the class. This is not really a predisposition towards magic, as anyone who has avoided birth defects and head trauma should find themselves suited to one spellcasting path or another.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127242/discussion-on-answer-by-oblivious-sage-how-to-detect-predisposition-for-magic-in).

Answer (score 5):

So this sort of thing is really a setting detail, and different D&D settings may have different answers—magic just somewhat works differently in Eberron, the Forgotten Realms, or Greyhawk. But D&D does have a sort of unnamed, implied generic setting; it doesn't have a lot of detail, and mostly seems like Greyhawk or the Forgotten Realms with the serial numbers filed off. And in that setting, **anyone can learn magic.**

#### Learning magic—wizardry

Wizardry is the magic of knowledge and learning. If you learn how to manipulate the arcane forces of the world by memorizing the appropriate mystical patterns, you can become a wizard and cast spells. It is difficult, and requires Intelligence, so it may actually be impossible for someone with a poor memory to do, much less well, but Intelligence can also be improved.

Under the latest version of the rules, the only requirement for becoming a wizard is a 13 or better in Intelligence. Actually, you don’t even need that if you start out as a wizard; that rule is for the optional multiclassing variant that lets you become a wizard later, after having been trained since childhood in some other class. The same was true for the previous 4th edition, where the Arcane Initiate multiclass feat required Int 13, and in 3rd edition, there was no requirement at all, though to learn a wizard spell required an Int of 10 + the spell’s level (so 10 for cantrips, 11 for 1st-level spells, etc.).

As the process for creating a wizard says,

> How did your character first come into contact with magic? How did you discover you had an aptitude for it? Do you have a natural talent, or **did you simply study hard and practice incessantly?**

<sup>(*Player’s Handbook*, 5th edition, pg. 113, **emphasis** mine)</sup>

Thus, putting in the work is sufficient. A good, strong memory—read, high Intelligence—will make you better at it, and if you’re primarily trained in another class you’ll need 13 Intelligence to suddenly take up wizardry as a secondary interest, but if you train these children in wizardry, they **can** become wizards, even if they’re not particularly great at it (unable to prepare a wide variety of spells at a time, difficulty forcing their spells upon others who would resist them).

(It may be worth noting that the artificer from *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* or *Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything* also runs on Intelligence, and artifice is described as “arcane magic harnessed as a form of science,” implying but not outright stating that one can also become an artificer solely through hard study.)

#### Other magic—rely on other sources that mostly anyone can reach

Now, not all spellcasters are wizards (or artificers).

- Warlocks may, or may not, study to learn how to contact their patrons, but ultimately their magic comes from the pact they make with that patron—and in some cases, the patron contacts the warlock rather than the other way around. Literally anyone can become a warlock.
- The priests, clerics and druids, paladins and rangers, require no particular magical disposition, just faith. “Faith” in this context is measured by Wisdom, which generally reflects how aware you are of the world around you and within you, but you can still *be one* with poor Wisdom.

#### Sorcery—the one form of magic that *does* require a predisposition

Sorcery happens by chance. You’re either born with it, or some very unlikely event imbues you with it, and neither is within anyone’s conscious control.

> Sorcerers carry a magical birthright conferred upon them by an exotic bloodline, some otherworldly influence, or exposure to unknown cosmic forces. One can’t study sorcery as one learns a language, […] No one choooses sorcery; the power chooses the sorcerer.

<sup>(*Player’s Handbook*, 5th edition, pg. 99)</sup>

So if you want these children to become sorcerers, you basically have to have gotten lucky. How can you tell if you’ve gotten lucky? **When they start to manifest sorcerous powers, you’ll know.** There is no other test—anyone *could* have latent sorcery within them, and never know it. Even later in life, the only requirement for becoming a sorcerer under the rules is to have Charisma 13—that is, for your force of personality and self to be strong enough to push the power in your blood to the fore.

If someone is a sorcerer, you know, obviously, that they had the potential for sorcery. If someone isn’t a sorcerer, you’ll never know for sure that they **can’t** be. And even if they really don’t have the potential, they might by some remote chance gain it later.

I don’t have a direct citation for the claim that you cannot detect latent sorcery or its absence. What I do have is an enormous amount of experience with the material of WotC-era D&D—and sorcerers (as we know them) didn’t even exist before WotC’s 3rd edition of the game. There has never been printed any spell, ritual, or other method for definitively detecting latent sorcery. And, as a matter of rules, each of those editions of the game allowed one to become a sorcerer at any time, at *most* requiring some minimum amount of Charisma. No effect in the game, in any of these editions, has ever stated “we now know you *can’t* be a sorcerer, and you are unable to take levels in that class.”

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127237/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-kryan).